# How to get remote HTTP Port number in spring servlet?

Tags: java, spring, http, httprequest, port

I need to extract client's IP and port number when he makes a request to the servlet.

Here's my controller code:

```
@Controller
public class IpCheckerController {

String ip;
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/ipchecker", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    for (String header : HEADERS_TO_TRY) {
        ip = request.getHeader(header);
        if (ip != null && ip.length() != 0 && !"unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
            return ip + "_"+request.getRemotePort(); // this port is wrong
                                                     // but I left it here for now.
        }
    }
    return request.getRemoteAddr() + "_"+request.getRemotePort();
}

private static final String[] HEADERS_TO_TRY = { 
    "X-Forwarded-For",
    "Proxy-Client-IP",
    "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_VIA",
    "REMOTE_ADDR" };
```

}

However it is not working as intended. At first I used `getRemoteAddr()` but it alays returns `127.0.0.1` or `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. Then I got this code from someone at work with checking for different headers and now it's working correctly.

However `getRemotePort()` returns wrong port. My application authentictes users based on ip and port I put into database on login. When someone makes and unauthorised attempt, logger writes down IP and port from which the attemps was made. This port is always different from what `getRemotePort()` shows.

What headers can I use to get the port just like with the IP? Is there a different way to extract port?

I can't use any extrernal services to parse this data, that's why I have to make my own servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port address would vary for different connections.

Here is a post explaining this: [HttpServletRequest.getRemotePort() returns different port per http request received on same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987456/httpservletrequest-getremoteport-returns-different-port-per-http-request-recei)

Comment: can I force my application to always use the same port per application instance?Once I login I need to keep sending the requests on the same port until I log out.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid the clients port from changing, this is due to the way a router handles routing traffic internally on its network. Essentially each time someone inside of a local network makes a request to the outside world the router assigns a random high port to that specific request. This is how you can have multiple people on one network making different http requests from a single IP address.